# Chef: Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ubuntu, networking, chef-infra, ubuntu-16.04

I ran "chef verify" in my workstation/local machine and got this error result.

```
mike@mike-pc:/opt/chefdk$ chef verify
 Running verification for component 'berkshelf'
 Running verification for component 'test-kitchen'
 Running verification for component 'tk-policyfile-provisioner'
 Running verification for component 'chef-client'
 Running verification for component 'chef-dk'
 Running verification for component 'chef-provisioning'
 Running verification for component 'chefspec'
 Running verification for component 'generated-cookbooks-pass-chefspec'
 Running verification for component 'rubocop'
 Running verification for component 'fauxhai'
 Running verification for component 'knife-spork'
 Running verification for component 'kitchen-vagrant'
 Running verification for component 'package installation'
 Running verification for component 'openssl'
 Running verification for component 'inspec'
 Running verification for component 'delivery-cli'
 Running verification for component 'git'
 Running verification for component 'opscode-pushy-client'
 Running verification for component 'chef-sugar'
 ...

 An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
 Failure/Error: raise InvalidURIError, "Invalid scheme format: #{new_scheme}"

Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError:
  Invalid scheme format: 127.0.0.1
 # /home/mike-pc/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.6.4/lib/berkshelf/source.rb:58:in `build_universe'
 # /home/mike-pc/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/berkshelf-5.6.4/lib/berkshelf/installer.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in build_universe'


 Finished in 0.25155 seconds (files took 1.57 seconds to load)
 0 examples, 0 failures
```

I executed "kitchen diagnose -all" and found out that I have invalid URI:

```
instances:
  default-centos-72:
    platform:
      os_type: unix
      shell_type: bourne
    state_file:
      hostname: 127.0.0.1
      last_action: create
      last_error: Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError
      port: '2222'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you can add log to the question or run `kitchen diagnose --all`

Comment: hi @AnkurJyotiPhukan, thanks. I updated it.

Comment: Have you installed chefdk on kitchen? Because 'kitchen diagnose' checks the status of running kitchen instance. Can you please update the log with "gem environment" output.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious:

```
Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError:
Invalid scheme format: 127.0.0.1
```

I think you are missing "http://" before the "127.0.0.1".

Comment: hi @Draco Ater, where can I set it? Thanks

Comment: Somewhere in your code may be?! `An error occurred in a 'before(:suite)' hook.`

Comment: I haven't write a code yet, I just install chefdk in my local machine and test it using "chef verify".

Answer (score 0):

`chef verify` is not a command you should be running. That's for the ChefDK developers and release team.